# validating a registration form in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have created a registration page which consists of name address pin code age..etc..
I want that the age and the piicode field should be restricted to number.I have tried to use **android:inputType="number" Or android:inputType="phone:"** But its not working..
Please give any suggestion.

Reigistration.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class Registration1 extends Activity  implements OnClickListener,
OnItemSelectedListener{

    private Button mSubmit;
    private Button mCancel;
    private EditText mGname;
    private EditText mFname;
    private EditText mMname;
    private EditText mAddress1;
    private EditText mAddress2;
    private EditText mCityvillage;
    private EditText mStateprovince;
    private EditText mCountry;
    private EditText mPostalcode;
    private EditText mAge;
    private EditText mBirthdate;
    private Spinner mGender;
    private EditText mUsername;
    private EditText mpass;

    private String Gen;

    protected static DBHelper1 DB1;
    String regexStr = "^[0-9]$";
    String regexStr1 ="\\d{3}";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration1);

        // Assignment of UI fields to the variables
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        mGname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.egname);
        mFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.efname);
        mMname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMname);
        mAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eaddress1);
        mAddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eaddress2);
        mCityvillage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecityvillage);
        mStateprovince = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.estateprovince);
        mCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecountry);
        mPostalcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epostalcode);
        mAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eage);
        mBirthdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebirthdate);
        mGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eusername);
        mpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epass);


        // Spinner method to read the on selected value
        ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] {
                        new State("Male"), new State("Female") });
        mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.cancel:
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // finish();
            break;

        case R.id.submit:
            System.out.println("rEGISTER BUTTON CLICK");
            String gname = mGname.getText().toString();
            String fname = mFname.getText().toString();
            String mname = mMname.getText().toString();
            String address1 = mAddress1.getText().toString();

            String address2 = mAddress2.getText().toString();
            String cityvillage = mCityvillage.getText().toString();
            String stateprovince = mStateprovince.getText().toString();
            String country = mCountry.getText().toString();

            String postalcode = mPostalcode.getText().toString();
            String age = mAge.getText().toString();
            String birthdate = mBirthdate.getText().toString();
            Gen = mGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = mpass.getText().toString();

            boolean invalid = false;

            if (gname.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Givenname",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else

            if (fname.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else

            if (mname.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your middlename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else

            if (address1.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your address1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else if (address2.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your address2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (cityvillage.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your cityvillage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (stateprovince.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your stateprovince", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (country.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if(postalcode.equals("")||postalcode.length()!=7||postalcode.matches(regexStr)==true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter valid postal code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }/*else if (postalcode.equals("")||postalcode.length() != 7) {
            }
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your postalcode Or postalcode must be 7 numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 if(postalcode.length() != 7)
                 {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "postalcode must be 7 numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }
            } */else if (age.equals("")||age.matches(regexStr1)==true) {
                //invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter valid age", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (birthdate.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your birthdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (username.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (password.equals("")||!(password.length() >= 6)) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Password must be at least 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if (invalid == false) 
            {
                addEntry(gname, fname, mname, address1, address2, cityvillage,
                        stateprovince, country, postalcode, age, birthdate, Gen,
                        username,password);
                Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration1.this,
                        LoginActivity1.class);
                startActivity(i_register);
                // finish();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //DB1.close();
    }

    private void addEntry(String gname,String fname,String mname,String address1,String address2,String cityvillage,String
            stateprovince,String country,String postalcode,String age,String birthdate,String Gen,String username,String password) 
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = DB1.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put("id", 2);
        values.put("givenname", gname);
        values.put("firstname", fname);
        values.put("middlename", mname);
        values.put("address1", address1);
        values.put("address2", address2);
        values.put("cityvillage", cityvillage);
        values.put("stateprovince", stateprovince);
        values.put("country", country);
        values.put("postalcode", postalcode);
        values.put("age", age);
        values.put("birthdate", birthdate);
        values.put("gender", Gen);
        values.put("username", username);
        values.put("password", password);

        try {
            long rowId = db1.insert(DBHelper1.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME1, null, values);
            System.out.println("rowId: "+rowId);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "your details submitted Successfully...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
        State st = (State) mGender.getSelectedItem();

        // Show it via a toast
        toastState("onItemSelected", st);
    }

    public void toastState(String name, State st) {
        if (st != null) {
            Gen = st.name;
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Gen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void setDB(DBHelper1 dB2) {
        DB1=dB2;

    }




}
```

registration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Given Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/egname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Family Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/efname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />


            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Middle Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eMname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Address1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eaddress1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Address2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eaddress2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityvillage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="City Village"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ecityvillage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stateprovince"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="State Province"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/estateprovince"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Country"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ecountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postalcode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Postal Code"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/epostalcode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="number"/>


         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Age"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="number"/>

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/birthdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="BirthDate"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ebirthdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eusername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/epass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Submit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submit"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You need to set up setOnTouchListener for the edittext

Comment: There are some specific attributes and some specific values that can be given to these attributes.Except these values,you can't give them of your own.There are no attribute values like phone or number for the `android:inputType`.Actually the logic you are implementing is completely wrong

Comment: how to do that??Can u please provide some sample example

Comment: android:inputType="number" should work, it will popup a keyboad with numbers with the help of which u can restricted the user to numbers only it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
postalcodeEDT.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            // (Check if 1.number, 2. Number within range
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also add the following to your xml file for postalcode field:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

---

**EDIT:**

For checking age in edit box, you can probably have an onfocuschangelistener as below:

```
ageEDT.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        EditText t = (EditText) v;
        if (t.getText() != null
                && !(t.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
            try {
                    // Allows age to be floating point too.
                Float i = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());
                if (i >= 100 && i <=5) { 
                            // If age > 100 and <5. 
                    t.setText("");
                    t.setFocusable(true);
                    AlertUserforFocus(
                            "Age",
                            "Invalid Value. Please enter between 5 to 100 !!\n",
                            t);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // If characters other than numbers is entered
                t.setText("");
                AlertUserforFocus(
                        "Age",
                        "Invalid Value. Please enter between 5 to 100 !!\n",
                        t);
            }
        }
    }
}

});
```

**Note:**

AlertUserforFocus(String title,String message,final EditText t) is a custom method for displaying an alertdialog to user. You can display toast or whatever as per your requirement.

Comment: how to limit these values to particular rage..like for example if I want to enter the age within 5 to 100.how to do that.Please help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mPostalcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epostalcode);
mPostalcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

or try in xml:

```
android:numeric="integer"
```

Comment: how to limit these values to particular rage..like for example if I want to enter the age within 5 to 100.how to do that.Please help